# Error with sympy.lambdify for piecewise functions and numpy module

Tags: numpy, sympy, piecewise, lambdify

In sympy 0.7.6, I had no troubles with the following code for both the modules='sympy' and the modules='numpy' options. Now with sympy v0.1, the evaluation with modules='numpy' raise a ZeroDivisionError:

```
import sympy

x, y = sympy.symbols(['x', 'y'])
expr = sympy.Piecewise((1/x, y < -1), (x, y <= 1), (1/x, True))

f_sympy = sympy.lambdify([x, y], expr, modules='sympy')
f_numpy = sympy.lambdify([x, y], expr, modules='numpy')

print f_sympy(0, 1)  # performs well

print f_numpy(0, 1) # issue: ZeroDivisionError
```

Seems like the piecewise functions evaluate before the condition with modules='numpy'.

My questions are:

Is this behavior normal?

If so, why, and how to define a piecewise expression and evaluate it as fast as with numpy module without the sympy.lambdify procedure?

EDIT:

Found that in my case the solution is theano:

```
import sympy

x, y = sympy.symbols(['x', 'y'])
f = sympy.Piecewise((1/x, y < -1), (x, y <= 1), (1/x, True))

from sympy.printing.theanocode import theano_function
f_theano = theano_function([x, y], [f])

print f_theano(0, 1)  # OK, return 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted my other answer (in case you already saw it). There is a much simpler solution.

The ZeroDivisionError comes because the lambdified expression produces, roughly, `lambda x, y: select([less(y, -1),less_equal(y, 1),True], [1/x,x,1/x], default=nan)`. The problem is that passing in x = 0 results in `1/0` being evaluated by Python, which raises the error.

But NumPy is just fine with dividing by zero. It will issue a warning, but otherwise works fine (it gives `inf`), and in this example there is no problem, because the `inf` is not actually used.

So the solution is to wrap the input to `lambdify` as numpy arrays, that is, instead of

```
f_numpy(0, 1)
```

use

```
f_numpy(array(0), array(1))
```

There is a [SymPy issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11306) discussing this if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you. This is much clearer for me now. I'll try the 'numpy.array' solution. 
For now, I use this workaround I made which invokes 'lambdarepr' and (unfortunately) 'eval':
https://gist.github.com/A-Falaize/ff2fafd5ab19f88c478f7494e340a619
This works for me, but is not very 'pythonic'. What are the drawbacks of such a solution?

Comment: I don't see how your poor-man's lambdify solves this issue. From what I can tell, everything that your function does, `sympy.lambdify` also does, but `sympy.lambdify` also does a lot more, so I would recommend just using it.